# Elastic search storing hierarchical data and querying it

Tags: elasticsearch

Let me break down the problem it will take some time.

Consider that you have an entities `A, B, C` in your system.

- `A` is the parent of everything
- `B` is the child of `A`
- `C` can be child of `A` or `B`, Please note there are some more entities like `D,E,F` which are same as `C`. So lets consider `C` only for time being

So basically its a tree alike structure like

````
   ```
     A
    / \
   /   \
  B     C(there are similar elements like D, E, F)
  |
  |
  C
   ```
````

Now we need are using `Elastic Search` as secondary DB to store this. In the data base the structure is completely different since `A, B, C` have dynamic fields, so they are different tables and we join them to get data, but from business prospective this is design.

Now when we try to flat it and store in es for under set

- We have a entity A1 who has 2 children C1 and B1, B1 has further children C2

  ### A         B         C

  1   A1       null       null
  2   A1       null       C1
  3   A1        B1        null
  4   A1        B1        C2

Now what your can query

- use says he wants All columns of A,B,C where value of columns A is `A1`, so adding some null removing rules we can give him row number 2,3,4
- now the problem set , now user says he want all `A`s where value of A is `A1` , so basically we will return him all rows 1,2,3,4 or 2,3,4 so we will see values like

  ### A

  A1
  A1
  A1

but logically he should see only one column `A1` since that is only unique value. As `ES` doesn't have the ability to `group by` things.

So how we solved things.

- We solved this problem by creating multiple indices and one nested index
- So when we need to group by index we go to nested index and other index work as flat index
- so we have different index, like index for `A and B`, `A or B and C` . But we have more elements so it lead to creation of 5 indices.
- As data started increasing its becoming difficult to maintain 5 indices and indexing them from scratch takes too much time.

So to solve this we started to look for other options and we are testing `cratedb`. But on the first place we are still trying to figure is there any way to do that in ES since need to use many feature of ES as `percolation`, `watcher` etc. Any clues on that?

Please also note that we need to apply pagination also. That's why single nested index will not work

Comment: `As ES doesn't have the ability to group by things.` => that's not correct, ES can group things using [aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html)

Comment: @Val but we cannot do pagination and stuff with grouping in Es if I am right like we can do in sql world

Comment: With a [composite aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html), paginating is possible

Comment: Okay let me check that one, Yeah just saw its in beta I think. I will read about it

Comment: It's still an experimental feature, but it works out pretty well, try it out.